# なるのではないか/なるのではないだろう meaning

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension, jlpt, written-language, rhetorical-questions

もっと人間関係を大切にすれば、100年前と同じような心豊か生活が送れるように _______ と思う。

1. なるのではないか
2. なるのではないかな
3. なるのではないだろう
4. なるのでないでしょう

1 is the correct anwser but I can't figure out why. I guess 4 is incorrect because it uses the です form. Is なるのではないか just a set phrase?  Does なるのではないだろう need か to be grammatically correct? Could someone please break down these phrases?

Comment: I am surprised that none of the native speakers have answered this yet, and I am not qualified to give a definite answer, but I would have thought ではないか and ではないだろう would both be acceptable, differing little. It helps to remember that the material before と in Japanese is 'direct speech', that is, the utterance actually spoken. With this in mind, 岸田文雄は日本の首相ではないか and 岸田文雄は日本の首相ではないだろう (this said with a rising intonation), I believe, mean the same thing, "Kishida Fumio is the Prime Minister of Japan, isn't he?".

Comment: If you add と思う then you simply get 'I think that...' (minus the 'tag' question at the end of course). ではないかな on the other hand seems more hesitant, 'I wonder if it might be that he is...', something along those lines and for that reason might be deemed to be incorrect here. Also,  かな questions are mostly directed at oneself, but meant to be overheard by the listener. This is my (perhaps faulty) understanding of the differences.

Comment: @N.Hunt it's important to remember that it's not strange for multiple choice questions to require you to pick the *best* out of the available choices, which doesn't necessarily imply that the other choices are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> Does なるのではないだろう need か to be grammatically correct?

No. All are grammatically fine. They can be used in appropriate sentences.

> Is なるのではないか just a set phrase?

Practically I think it's better for learners to treat (の)ではないか as a pattern, as many Web resources seem to do. *Sentence + のではないか* means *isn't it the case that Sentence?*

The importance of か here is to add doubt. Without it, it is a simple negative sentence. It would mean *(I think) it isn't the case that we will live better*. By adding か, doubt+ではない works like a double negative=positive, meaning *I think it **is** the case that we live better*. Or, as mentioned above, it makes a (rhetoric) question: *isn't it the case*  (I wonder, isn't it the case that ...?, yes it is).

---

I think 2 fits ok, too. 1 is correct probably because it is about のではないか as a pattern.

Also, なるのではないだろう**か** can work (3+か).